# Is there a way to allow a list of specific values for a cell in a DataTable only?

Tags: c#, datatable

I wonder if there is a good way to allow a list of speccific values for a cell in a DataTable and block the rest?
Couldn't find something online.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "allow" and "block"?

Comment: DataTable is just the storage engine in a way. What GUI element are you using to fill it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean.  But you can use validations:

[Walkthrough: Adding Validation to a Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171930%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
[Validating Data During Row Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1120xds5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to allow specific values only and that for other values, it won't try to update. Maybe I can just use a list in the datagridview instead of textbox! right? I think I have seen it somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to listen to the DataTable's RowChanging event. There you can check whether your limited DataColumn is the modified one and if needed reject the change. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanging

Comment: I thought about it too. I think it's a good way, problem is: say we have a list of allowed values, how do you pass that list to the RowChanging event? Thanks.

Comment: You can set an ExtendedProperty for the Column. I did not try but from what the MSDN says I guess that you could even set something other then a string as long as you do not want to persist it.